# StartApp not showing in Android app

Tags: android, startapp

I used `StartApp SDK 3.1.1` in `Android Studio`  and I follow this link (Step 1 to  Showing Banner):
https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/Android-InApp-Documentation

1. Import SDK jar
2. Insert code into **AndroidManifest.xml**:

   and under :

   `<activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
   <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.OverlayActivity"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
   <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.FullScreenActivity"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme"
         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />`
3. Call method `StartAppSDK.init(this, "Your Account Id", "Your App ID", true);` with replaced my account id and my app id before `setContentView()`

4.Showing **banner** with

`<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner 
          android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>`

But when I build app banner not showing.

Comment: Please contact StartApp support at support@startapp.com

Comment: I have solved it. Follow `StartAppSDK.init(this, "Your Account Id", "Your App ID", true);` but replace `App ID` to `AD UNIT ID` of banner that is created in setting

Answer (score 0):

*In your main activity, go to the OnCreate method and before calling setContentView() call the static function:*
**StartAppSDK.init(this, "Your App ID", true);**